# Can't seem to get my positioning right. CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm making a portfolio site as my first programming project, and I'm having some trouble with positioning. I have 2 elements at the top that I'd like to be in the center but are off by a little, and also I have my webpage divided into two columns but the second one doesn't really line up completely for whatever reason.

To be more specific, there is an arrow at the top which should be in the center(horizontally) of the page, text with a border saying "home page" that should be centered too.

and in the right column the header of "Contact Form" Does not align with the left of the contact form and neither does the submit button.

Also how do I make it so that the input fields' border in the form don't change color when selected.

[Here is the JSFiddle for this](https://jsfiddle.net/4k61pr9a/)
Thanks I appreciate it alot.

MY HTML (It's really a PHP file because it has a contact form but mostly html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php include ('form_process.php');?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1 shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/contact.css">
    <title>Contact</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid top email">
        <a  href="hamburger.html" class="fa fa-arrow-up back_button" ></a>
        <p class="homepage">Home Page</p>
        <div class="email_form">  
            <div class="row">


            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="left col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-1 hidden-xs">
                    <h3>Contact Me</h3>
                    <p class="">If you want to get in touch with me, I'd love to talk! Feel free to use the contact form to the right, or contact me on social media.</p>
                    <p>mail: myemail@gmail.com</p>
                    <h3>Find Me On</h3>
                    <p>facebook twitter instagram</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Deserunt ullam, veritatis quo. Voluptate, nihil odio cum. Voluptas ipsam, sit accusantium rem perferendis, voluptatibus obcaecati quisquam adipisci eum, id dignissimos aliquam non. Sequi culpa, modi quod, repellendus, doloribus incidunt excepturi fugiat aperiam totam quos provident voluptatibus aliquid voluptate repellat at suscipit vel dicta alias? Sint accusantium nihil qui sit voluptates assumenda suscipit quod nulla asperiores tempora, modi eaque quis non expedita odit ipsum, illo ad praesentium labore! Fugiat officiis natus suscipit. Architecto aut neque minima dolorum iste saepe totam voluptas earum, tempora fugit ullam harum velit debitis maxime provident. Recusandae, aliquam.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-offset-2">
                    <form id="contact" action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
                        <h3>Contact Form</h3>
                        <div class="form-group row">

                            <div>
                                <label for="name">Name*</label>
                                <input class="form-control input-default" id="name" placeholder="Your Full Name" type="text" tabindex="1" size="30" name="name" value="<?= $name ?>" autofocus>
                                <span class="error"><?= $name_error?> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div >
                                <label for="email">Email Address*</label> 
                                <input class="form-control input-default" id="email" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>" tabindex="2" >
                                <span class="error"><?= $email_error?> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div >
                                <label for="subject">Subject*</label> 
                                <input class="form-control input-default" id="subject" placeholder="Your Subject" type="text" name="subject" value="<?= $subject ?>" tabindex="2" >
                                <span class="error"><?= $subject_error?> </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div >
                                <label for="message">Message*</label>
                                <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." class="message1 form-control input-default" rows="5" id="message" name="message" tabindex="5" ><?php if(isset($_POST['message'])){ 
                                    echo htmlentities ($_POST['message']); }?></textarea>
                                    <span class="error"><?= $message_error?></span> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <button class="btn-default btn rbutton" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="success"><?= $success;?></div>
                        </form>

                    </div>

                </div>


            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

MY CSS:

```
    body{
    background: #0ac2d2;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
label, p{
    color: white;
}
.input-default, .input-default:after, .inpute-default:visited{
    border: 2px solid white;
    background-color: #0ac2d2;
}
.email_form{
    margin-top: 25px;
}
h3{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #E06B65;
}
.back_button{
    margin-top: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50%; 
    margin-right: 50%; 
    font-size: 28px;
    color: white;
    padding: 0;
    transition: transform .5s;

}

.back_button:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    transform: translateY(-20px);
}
.homepage{
    font-size: 16px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-right: 50%;
    border: solid 1px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playing with it a bit, i removed all except one of the problem elements, leaving me with pretty much just this for the html:

```
<body>
    <p class="homepage">Home Page</p>
</body>
```

That helps isolate it. Great. However, still offset to the right.

Looking at the CSS, it seems that the issue is the  margin-left and margin-right:

```
margin-left: 50%;
margin-right: 50%;
```

That's not a great way to center the text, since you've made the margins occupy 100% of the width. It'll start drawing the text to the right of the left margin, which means right in the middle of the page, and keep drawing to the right, making it off center.

There's probably another way to get that centered. Maybe wrap it in another row and let bootstrap take care of it? That would mean getting rid of the margin-left and margin-right on .back-button and .homepage in your CSS, and using this for those elements in the html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
        <a  href="hamburger.html" class="fa fa-arrow-up back_button" ></a>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="text-center">
        <p class="homepage">Home Page</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You should be able to go thru similar troubleshooting to come up with ways to fix the other alignment issues (and it looks like there has been at least one other answer in the time i spent typing, hehe).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll want to do is change your button from `display: inline-block` to `display: block`. Instead of giving it `margin-left: 50%`, you'll want to give it `margin 0 auto` to automatically align it in the middle, and set a fixed `width`:

```
.homepage {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

As for your `.back_button`, it will need similar rules:

```
.fa.back_button {
  display: block !important;
  margin: 15px auto 10px;
}
```

Note that the selector has changed to `.fa.back_button`. This is to give it increased specificity and overwrite the FontAwesome rules which are slightly more specific. The extra margins simply return to to how it was displaying as an `inline-block` element.

The easiest way to get your `Contact Form` header and submission button to align is to offset the `col` class added by Boostrap. This can be done by simply giving them the class of `row`, which adds the relevant negative margins:

```
<h3 class="row">Contact Form</h3>
 ...
<div class="row">
  <button class="btn-default btn rbutton" name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
</div>
```

As for the borders changing colour on hover, that all comes from Bootstrap:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

Simply overwriting these rules will resolve the problem:

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: white;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

This can all be seen in **[this example](https://jsfiddle.net/vfvcxhd8/)**.